# HTML5 footer - margin that I can't remove

Tags: css, html

I've started a site based on HTML 5 Boilerplate and I want a basically all white site but a grey background to my footer. Problem is that there is a margin (and pretty sure it's a margin not padding or white border) below the footer leaving a white strip below my grey footer.

I've cut everything down in order to post here and moved my CSS inline, plus changed the colours to make it more visable;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="background:#C0C0C0;">
    <img src="1by1.gif" width="700" height="1000" border="0" alt="">
        <div style="border-top: 1px solid #666366;background:#FFFF33;">
            <footer style=" max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;">
                footer
            </footer>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it's [online here](http://solomon.ie/so/footer.html)

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: where is your body and html tag? does the boilerplate set margin:0; padding:0; on both those?

Comment: You really need to add normalize.css as H5BP bases so much on it. It's essential for what you're doing.

Comment: sorry, prpblem with pasting in code corrected now

Comment: yes, i use normalize.css - this is just a bare bones demo of my issue

Comment: Think I found it - yes, setting margin :0 for body worked on my code above, but not in the real code I've not posted here. In my actual footer i had a <p> and in normalize.css it adds margin: 1em 0; to Ps -footer p {margin: 0;padding: 0;} seems to fix my issue. Why did the <P> margin extend beyond the <footer> it is contained in>?

Answer (score 3):

You have a margin on your body:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

should solve the issue

Comment: body { margin: 0;} is already in normalize.cssm but added the above to my main.css (in my fully coded version) still the same

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

Or (better) include [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) in your page.

Comment: Even better: `margin-bottom: 0; `

Answer (score 1):

Only adding one thing can give you the solution that is-

add margin:0 to body
body { margin:0; }

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Try this: inside the footer put a `<p>` paragraph. And then make a css rule for the 'footer p', where you set the proper margin.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna make footer without margin in the bottom you can add only the height attribute in your css file and delete the margin bottom if existed.

```
footer{
  height : 120px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```